# Amperage measurements using a analog multimeter

Tags: multimeter

I got this $15.00 Multimeter with Amperage measurement. Do I need to put the test probes in series on the circuit? The maximum range on the multimeter is 250mA. The black probe is connected to the 10A Max socket.

[image: The multimeter looks like this]

Comment: Do you have an image of the meter?

Comment: -1 for bad quality question.

Comment: Was there a manual shipped with this $15 ware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of "mains" hints that you are British? If you are in the UK you will be dealing with 240VAC which is a) very dangerous and b) not measurable by this **DC** ammeter.

If you want to measure AC current in anything mains-powered you want a clamp-on ammeter - no bare connectors to electrocute you and it's highly unlikely the measuring device will ignite.

You also need a breakout cable - you need to put the clamp around just the hot wire or it won't work. Any specialty shop that sells clamp-on ammeters will also have the cable, if it's not included in the package.

If all you want is the operating and standby wattage of common appliances, it's usually on a label near the power cord. Note that "operating" is usually maximum - for a TV that's full brightness and decently loud.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when measuring current the probes should be in series.

From the poor quality image I think I can make out the 0-10 A range just underneath the mirror (the label seems to read "DC V A").

Comment: What if I connect the probes in series to the mains and a television. Will it be ok? Because I want to get the wattage of some appliances. Watts = volts * amps right?

Comment: For the sake of safety you should a proper AC power meter for this rather than a cheap multimeter. And yes P=IV.